# Get number of elements in Imacros

Tags: imacros

There are 10 li tags in an html. I need the number to use it with a loop in a vbs file.

I tried this simple code but it didn't work, even in firefox extension

```
 URL GOTO=javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('movableListItem').length;
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please explain.

Comment: I want to calculate the number of elements of a same class, with javascript this is easy. But imacros can't access webpage dom

Comment: The JS scripting could do that but iMacros alone I don't know.

Comment: iMacros can't access the dom. So I thought do it with error throwing of the imacros object in a vbscript, but that it's too for a simple task. So I tried Selenium and it could do it pretty good in a single line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imacros can do it but you need to make a loop and catch the first error. It's kinda complicated for just this simple question but in Selenium IDE just do this:

```
Command: storeCssCount
Target : css=a
Value  : n
```

And that's all. A single line of code

Answer (score 1):

One can try the code below to set the built-in variable !EXTRACT to the number of image tags in a document. And your question is similar.

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.document.getElementsByTagName("img").length}
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.history.back()}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
BACK
```

Comment: But you need to reload the webpage in every run